# How do I install the new version of HPLIP?

Tags: software-installation

Trying to get my HP Officejet 5740 working with scanning. Everything I find is outdated or not working. When I try to run the hp-setup command, I get this below:

```
error: HPLIP is not installed properly or is installed without graphical support. Please reinstall HPLIP
warning: Qt/PyQt 4 initialization failed.
error: hp-setup requires GUI support (try running with --qt3). Also, try using interactive (-i) mode.
```

I can print to the printer, but that’s it. Can anyone help me out with this? Really need help getting scanning working.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I installed HPLIP 3.15.11 to support a HP Color LaserJet M277n on Freya 0.3.1:

## Remove old HPLIP

```
sudo apt-get remove hplip
```

## Install dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install gcc build-essential python-dev libcups2-dev libusb-1.0-0 libtool libcupsimage2-dev libsane-dev libsnmp-dev python-qt4 python-qt4-dbus python-dev xsane
```

## Set a root password, the installer will ask for it

```
sudo passwd (somepass)
```

## Run the installer

```
sh hplip-3.15.11.run
```

Choose auto installation
Distro selection: Ubuntu, 14.04

Installer defaults for everything else

Auto discovery didn't find anything, but a manual IP address selection worked fine.  I was prompted to run 'hp-plugin' to install a binary plugin for this printer during the printer setup process.

Printing and scanning now both work for me.

Comment: Why does this require setting a root password?

Comment: @embik the hplip installer specifically asks for it, and is unhappy running under sudo - more info here: http://hplipopensource.com/node/316

Answer (score 1):

HP Officejet 5740 is working with the new HPLIP which you can get here.

http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/index.html

http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/models/officejet/officejet_5740_series.html

Don't forget to deinstall the version of hplip and hplip-gui you have already installed.

And further. If you have already installed freya 0.3.1 so you have to choose Ubuntu 15.04 in the download area on the HPLIP website.

Comment: I've tried already, I'm getting multiple problems. If I try to run the installer with sudo, I go through the wizard and get 

note: Installation of dependencies requires an active internet connection.
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency: libusb (libusb - USB library)
warning: This installer cannot install 'libusb' for your distro/OS and/or version.
error: Installation cannot continue without this dependency. Please manually install this dependency and re-run this installer.

Comment: I've managed to shorten the list of missing dependencies, but unable to download these below. pyqt4,sane-devel
pyqt4-dbus          
python-devel

Comment: I've the same problem. I want to install an newer version of hplip because i bought a new printer. But the dependencies failed my installation every time.

Comment: Yup, I got the same problem about a month ago. hplip doesn't recognize that elementary OS is based upon Ubuntu, so you're going to have to install every single dependency manually to make it work. `pyqt4` is actually `python-qt4`, `pyqt4-dbus` is `python-qt4-dbus`, `python-devel` is actually `python-dev`. So, after we combine all of that, `sudo apt-get install python-qt4 python-qt4-dbus python-dev` should do the trick.

Comment: @r3bl can you post this as an answer?

Comment: @RolandiXor This is more like a supplement to this answer than the answer itself.