# Unable to install HPLIP 3.15.7 because of dependencies

Tags: software-installation

I've tried to install hplip-3.15.7.run which I downloaded from hplipopensource. When I run the file, I always get stuck on the missing required dependencies as below. It does not give specific dependencies that I need to install.

> ### MISSING DEPENDENCIES
>
> Following dependencies are not installed. HPLIP will not work if all REQUIRED dependencies are not installed and some
>   of the HPLIP features will not work if OPTIONAL dependencies are not
>   installed. Package-Name         Component            Required/Optional
>   libnetsnmp-devel     network              REQUIRED
>   sane-devel           scan                 REQUIRED             xsane
>   scan                 OPTIONAL             gcc                  base
>   REQUIRED             dbus                 fax
>   REQUIRED

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find the dependency list for HPLIP here:

[HPLIP Dependency List](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/install/manual/distros/other.html)

Here's a blog showing guidelines on installing HPLIP and it's dependencies on elementary:

[HP Printer Setup Under Elementary OS](http://michael-peeters.blogspot.in/2013/10/hp-printer-setup-under-elementary-os_20.html)

And here is a similar question like yours which says, if you are using elementary 0.3.1, you need to choose ubuntu 15.04 in the download area of the HPLIP website.

[Install New Version Of HPLIP](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1871/how-do-i-install-the-new-version-of-hplip)

Comment: Finally a guide that solved my problem. Thanks you sir @godslayer